# Avoiding duplicate JS object properties from a single assignment operation?

Tags: javascript, database

I am running a script on a large dataset to expand existing information. e.g:

```
...
{
    id : 1234567890
},
{
    id : 1234567891
},
...
```

becomes

```
...
{
    id : 1234567890,
    Name : "Joe"
},
{
    id : 1234567891,
    Name : "Bob"
},
...
```

I am doing this via the following code:

```
for(var cur in members)
{
    curMember = members[cur];
    // fetch account based on curMember.id to 'curAccount'

    if(curAccount != null)
    {
        curMember.DisplayName = curAccount.DisplayName;
    }
}
```

For the most part, this works as expected. However, once in a while (in the order of tens of thousands of entries), the result looks like this:

```
...
{
    id : 1234567891,
    Name : "Bob",
    Name : "Bob"
},
...
```

I now have data which is in an invalid format and cannot be read by the DB, since duplicate property names doesn't make sense. It is occurring for random entries when the script is re-run, not the same ones every time. I need either a way to PREVENT this from happening, or to DETECT that it has happened so I can simply reprocess the entry. Anyone know what's going on here?

EDIT: After further investigation, the problem appears to occur only when the objects being modified come from a MongoDB query. It seems that if code explicitly sets a value to the same element name more than once, the field will be duplicated. All elements of the same name appear to be set to the most recently specified value. If it is only assigned once as in my original problem, it is only duplicated very rarely. I am using MongoDB 2.4.1.

Comment: a) don't use for-in-loops on arrays b) it's impossible to have a duplicate property on a js object. Is your JS engine buggy (which one do you use)? And how exactly do you get that output?

Comment: @Bergi - I'm confident that the JS engine is not buggy. Primarily because no JS engine would contain such a stupid bug. Secondarily because JS objects are usually implemented as either red black trees or hash tables which prevent two fields from having the same name.

Comment: a) thanks for the tip, will change it
b) I realize it should be totally impossible and does not make sense! I am running this on a MongoDB 2.4.1 which uses ES5. Details: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4-javascript/. I get the output via printjson(members) after the loop finishes but before I commit back to the DB.

Comment: @AaditMShah: I know, that is what frightens me :-) Maybe it occours as the result of a race condition due to the V8 parallelisation in mongodb…

Comment: I just printed out all data more directly via "for(var key in curMember) print(key + " : " + curMember[key]);" to verify that the problem wasn't with printjson. The duplicate key still showed up there, so it does look like it is somehow in the actual object state.

Comment: @Kevin: And `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(curMember)` does contain the duplicate? What happens if you `delete curMember.Name`, does it leave one property?

Comment: @Bergi Just tested - Object.getOwnPropertyNames() does **not** list the duplicates even when they are known to exist via my other methods of printing. delete curMember.Name appears to delete **all** copies

Comment: see my edit on the original question for additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it all figured out. MongoDB has a bug up to shell version 2.4.1 which allows duplicate element names to be set for query result objects. Version 2.4.3, released just this Monday, has a fix. See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9066.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get your problem. If you apply identical property names to an object in ECMAscript, that property will just get overwritten. The construct in your snippet, can never be exist in that form on a live-object (excluding JSON strings).

If you just want to *detect* the attempt to create a property which is already there, you either need to have that object reference cached beforehand (so you can loop its keys) - or -
you need to apply *ES5 strict mode*.

```
"use strict";
```

at the top of your file or function. That will assure that your interpreter will throw an exception on the attempt to create two identical property keys. <strike>You can of course, use a `try - catch` statement to intercept that failure then.</strike>

Seems like you cannot intercept errors which get thrown because of *strict mode violation*.